# Duplication of items in a Javascript Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set, ecmascript-5

I was going through basics of Javscript Set.According to its defintion, **A Set is a special type collection – “set of values” (without keys), where each value may occur only once.**

But I see when it comes to reference types the behavior is different. Consider the following snippet:

```js
let set = new Set();
let john = { name: "John" };
let pete = { name: "Pete" };
let mary = { name: "Mary" };
set.add(john);
set.add(pete);
set.add(mary);
set.add(john);
set.add(mary);
console.log("Scenario 1");
for (let user of set) {
  console.log(user.name);
}

let set1 = new Set();
set1.add({ name: "John" });
set1.add({ name: "Pete" });
set1.add({ name: "Mary" });
set1.add({ name: "John" });
console.log("Scenario 2");
for (let user of set1) {
  console.log(user.name);
}
```

I see in the scenario 1, it wont allow duplicates to be added as they are the same references. But in scenario 2 I see duplicates are being added.

Can some explain this behavior? Or Am I missing something.

How scenario 1 is different from 2?

Comment: But, you've answered your own question. They are different in memory

Comment: How scenario 1 is different from 2?

Comment: A Set does not look at the contents of the object itself.  It only looks at the pointer to the object.  If it's not a pointer to the same physical object, then it's allowed to be added to the Set as a different object.  In fact, you can add an object to the set and then change it's contents afterwards because the fact that it's in the set has NOTHING to do with the contents of the object, only the physical pointer to the object.  If it's not the same pointer to the same object, then it can be added separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Set does not look at the contents of the object itself. It only looks at the pointer to the object.

If it's not a pointer to the same physical object, then it's allowed to be added to the Set as a different physical object. In fact, you can add an object to the set and then change it's contents afterwards because the fact that it's in the set has NOTHING to do with the contents of the object, only the physical pointer to the object. If it's not the same pointer to the same object, then it can be added separately.

Here's an example:

```js
let s = new Set();
let x1 = {name: "John"};
let x2 = {name: "John"};

console.log(x1 === x2);    // false, not the same physical object

s.add(x1);
console.log(s.has(x1));    // true
console.log(s.has(x2));    // false
s.add(x2);
console.log(s.has(x2));    // true
console.log(Array.from(s));      // [{name: "John"}, {name: "John"}];

// now modify x1
x1.name = "Bob";
// the x1 object is still in the set, even though you modified it
// because being in the set has NOTHING to do with the contents of the object at all
console.log(s.has(x1));    // true
console.log(Array.from(s));   // [{name: "Bob"}, {name: "John"}];
```

Comment: Thanks makes sense:)

Comment: whenever I try adding let x1 = {name: "John"} twice, does it check if there is an entry at that particular memory location?

Comment: @li97 - Well, it's kind of up to the actual interpreter and the Set implementation how it determines whether it's the same physical object or not.  That level of implementation detail is not required in the spec.  It just has to not let the same physical object be entered more than once.  It could be checking an actual memory pointer or it could be that each object has some sort of internal ID that isn't just its memory location.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a check of `{name: 'John'} === {name: 'John'}`. You would find it returns false.

Every new object has a different reference even though the contents can be same. If it gives false to you, the `Set` would consider it a different element too.

---

When you assign a variable with a Reference value, its memory location gets copied.

For example:

```
let john = {name: 'John'} // lets say memory: XYZ
```

So, every time when you do: `set.add(john);`, you are adding the memory location in the set. So, the Set would see you adding `XYZ` everytime and it won't accept duplicates.

In the second case, 
When you do:

```
`set1.add({ name: "John" });` // You added maybe XYF
`set1.add({ name: "John" });` // You added maybe XYN
```

So, your Set treats them differently and adds both of them.

Comment: Thanks makes sense:)